# How to be a better candidate for a job at a particular company?

Tags: job-search

There's a company where I'd really like to work. They frequently post openings for positions in my field (in different departments), and I've applied several times (usually through recruiting agencies), but I've never been selected.

I'd like to know if there was something in my resume or background that is negatively affecting my chances. As usual, the hiring managers never provide feedback.

I have three LinkedIn contacts at that company, and I wrote to them two weeks ago to ask what I could do to be a better candidate. As yet, none of them have responded.

What would be a good course of action?

EDIT: Several of you have advised me to have my resume reviewed by others. I belong to a group for job-hunting professionals, and we regularly get professional and experienced advice on our resumes. Mine was good enough to get interviews for two roles, and prescreening tests for at least three, at the company in question. I'm hoping to learn why I haven't gotten any further.

Comment: How many professional friends have you shown your resume to for constructive feedback? In any case, going through recruiting agencies (unless they have exclusivity) will negatively affect your chances. Also, you should apply to other companies as well. Refining your approach and trying to get a job with other companies is very important as well. Looking for a job is a lot like dating. The more you date other people, the better at it you become.

Answer (score 1):

Ask for professional help. There are companies out there which specialize in helping people market themselves - including help with resumes/cover letters, etc.

It could also be that you're targeting jobs for which you're simply unsuited. or that something about your resume (the way you express yourself, or the way it's formatted) is simply off-putting.

Again, either get someone's help who really knows what they're doing, or contact a professional.

Generally speaking managers will not be interested in discussing why you were not selected for an interview, as they reject hundreds of applicants - they can't possibly take the time to reply to each and every one.

Comment: Be careful -- there are a lot of shady firms offering help with resumes and cover letters.